# How do I create a seconds timer?

Tags: java, timer

I'd like my `int time = 0` to increase by 1 every second, with the ability to pause and resume.

Answer (score 1):

For timers start here [java timers tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) give it a crack and ask another question when you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

```
final AtomicLong i = new AtomicLong(0);
Thread th = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                long lastSeconds = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
                sleep(100);
                long delta = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 - lastSeconds;
                i.getAndAdd(delta);
                if (delta > 0)
                    System.out.println(i.get());
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

th.start();
```